# basic egit operations

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have installed [egit](http://eclipse.org/egit/), and by using `Team - Share - commit`, assume that I now have a copy of the entire project in the `.git` directory.

So I do some work on the project and do another commit.

Now if I want to work on the first commit version what steps are needed?
Which egit command gets the saved project and how do I keep it separate from the current project.
Will it show up somewhere that also appears in the Navigation window of Eclipse?

Very basic stuff but as you can tell I am somewhat unclear about how the whole thing works.
I've googled as much as I can around tutorials but I find it difficult to relate to the terms and concepts that seem to be taken for granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to click the reset button (or menu team > Reset), and do a `reset --hard` on the refs you want.

Here is me working on V2 on my "`HelloWorld`" App, wanting to redo it completely, starting from V1 which in in `master HEAD`:

[image: git reset --hard on Egit]

---

But if you don't want to lose anything (even though a reset --hard doesn't lose any commits, [they are still available through the **`reflog`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718672/git-lost-commits)), another option is to use the history view to create and checkout a new branch from a previous commit:

[image: git checkout on EGit]

As you can see, your content is reset to that previous commit, referenced by a new branch (i.e. you can work without being in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) mode [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009)), and the package explorer reflects said new branch:

[image: git checkout done on Egit]

Comment: thanks for taking the trouble to include screen shots which are a great help.  I have backed up my project and then done some committing,changing, branching experiments.  Do you know of a tutorial (pref online) that explains in basic, simple terms the concept of things like heads, branches, detached heads etc?

Comment: @ron: one tutorial for Egit is http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html. For Git itself, I really recommend following the steps of http://gitimmersion.com/ (to be made with the CLI -- Command Line Interface -- of Git, like msysgit on Windows: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). As For the version control terms used in Git, the visual Git reference is nice: http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html. But the Pro Git book is equally useful: http://progit.org/book/