# How to pull work from particular commit

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I checkout to previous commit and then accidentally added and commit on that commit, now when i checked out to dev branch my work vanished, how can i retrieve my work

[image]

the commit on which i checked out displaying as ((741a...) and then i git add . and git commit the commit changes ((5b78c...)

Comment: This should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/135614/9083959

Comment: can you explain what happened here, where would be my work?

Comment: You where on a detached head (if I understand your question correctly). This explains it pretty well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229202/9083959

Comment: `git checkout commitId`

Comment: and how can i send my work to git checkout dev?

Comment: @lukas-reineke yes exactly detached, how can i move my work from detached head to dev branch

Comment: find the commit with reflog, checkout dev and cherry-pick the commit.

Comment: how can i find that commit inside commit, on git bash its only showing some initial number, let me show image

Comment: I think you need a quick brush up on some git fundamentals. What a commit is and what a conflict is.

Comment: tell me the right way :P

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): that will give you the last commit you just did before switching branches.

Then cherry-pick said commit to your current `dev` branch, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21388672/6309), using [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

```
git cherry-pick <commitSHA>
```